# return to the same activity, When restart the app

Tags: android, android-activity, return

I have a lot of activities in my app, and I want that if the user closes the app in activity 13 for example, when opening the app  at another time  the activity returns in activitty n°  13. how can I do this? thank in advance

Answer (score 2):

You could use SharedPreferences to keep track of the last used activity.

Then you can redirect the user in the onCreate of your main activity to the correct activity, and call finish on your main activity.

This could look something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    (...)
    int last_activity = getLastActivityIdFromSharedPreferences();
    if (last_activity == 1)
    {
        this.startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityOne.class));
        finish();
    }
    (...)
}
```

Comment: but that in this way the method is reminiscent of the activity last open?

Comment: Yes, this would be the redirect for your mainActivity. And then you have to override one of the Activity Lifecycle methods in each of your other activities to keep track of the current activity. In the onStart for example.

Comment: ahh understand ... I have to change these values ​​for all the activities that I have?
maquando insert this opens me the method in a row, I have to enter as a value?

Comment: private int getLastActivityIdFromSharedPreferences() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return 0;
 }

Comment: Yes, create your own mapping for your activities. More info on how to use SharedPreferences here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: and I'm sorry if I have a splash activity I have to insert it into the spash activity this code? or always in the main

Comment: no, I realized that I can not do this, because when I return to mainactivity
method changes the activity thanks anyway